# pgfplots: will addplot table include and ignore header automatically?

Tags: pgfplots

The `test.dat` is shown as below which contains three points:

```
1 3
2 2
5 5
```

The code is simply to plot lines:

```tex
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            title=test,
            xlabel={$x$},
            ylabel={$y$},
        ]
        \addplot [blue] table {test.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

According to [tikz.dev / PGFplots Manual](https://tikz.dev/pgfplots/reference-addplot#pgfp./pgfplots/table/header), the default `header` is `true`. In my understanding, pgfplots would take the first line as the `header` in this regard. My question is: is pgfplots intelligent enough to include or ignore the header automatically?

I also tried to add a header into `test.dat`, the result is the same:

```
x y
1 3
2 2
5 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, PGFPlots can recognize column names from a file. If your `test.dat` file has more than two columns, such as

```
first second third
  1     3      4
  2     2      5
  5     5      6
```

then you can choose which columns you want in your graph by specifying `header = true` and setting `x = ...` and `y = ...` to the names of columns:

```tex
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            title=test,
            xlabel={$x$},
            ylabel={$y$},
        ]
        \addplot [blue] table[header = true, x = first, y = third] {test.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Without `header = true`, PGFPlots will complain that it cannot find the columns `first` or `third`.

---

In your original `test.dat`, the reason why the first row was parsed as data rather than column names was because column names cannot be purely numerical. As a result, PGFPlots was interpreting the first row as numerical data, even though `header` is `true` by default. From the documentation,

> Use `\addplot table [header=false]{⟨`*`file name`*`⟩}` if your input file has no column names. Otherwise, the first non-comment line is checked for column names: if all entries are numbers, they are treated as numerical data; if one of them is not a number, all are treated as column names.